# Check Bluetooth Connection Status on Python3, Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, windows-10

I've gone through [python bluetooth - check connection status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325218/python-bluetooth-check-connection-status) and multiple other posts, but they seem dedicated to **anything other than Windows**. How would I be able to check if a Bluetooth device on Windows 10 is connected/disconnected if I have it's MAC address?